# Lists that implement an Interface, and passing a reference to that list

Tags: c#, list, reference

I have several different lists of objects, ie

```
List<Character> characters;
// ...
```

and some of those lists are of objects that implement the same interface:

```
public interface IDebugPrints
// ...

public class Character : IDebugPrints
// ...
```

I have a class where I would like to store a reference to a list (passed to it in its constructor) that implements IDebugPrints, ie

```
List<IDebugPrints> inList
```

So that later I can iterate through that list (in this case to print out debug information about the current *entries* in the original List).

I can't figure out how to do this. If I pass the List as IEnumerable, it makes a *copy* of the original list, which dosent work for me since objects are added and removed from the original list after that copy.

Any help is appreciated. I have a feeling this isnt possible based on a few other questions here on SO, but would appreciate confirmation.

EDIT:

Here is a bit more pseudo code:

```
public interface IDebugPrints
// ...

public class Character : IDebugPrints
// ...

public class StoreList
{
    private List<IDebugPrints> internalList;

    public StoreList( List<IDebugPrints> inList )
    {
         internalList = inList;
    }
}

// The I have the various lists, for example
List<Character> characters;

// ...

// And I want to pass that list
StoreList sl = new StoreList( characters );
```

This last line gives compile errors:

```
Cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<Character> to Systems.Collections.Generic.List<IDebugPrints>
```

Comment: Pass the list as a List<IDebugPrints>. Why doesn't that work? Also, even if passed as an IE<IDepugPrints> no copy would be made. In .NET there is never an implicit copy of a reference type object.

Comment: Could you provide more code and explain what is exactly your problem?

Comment: Sure, edited the original post with more details. The specific problem is: I'm working on a game that has various lists of objects. I'd like a generic way to dump the contents of those lists to my debug console via a console command. So I have any classes which I want to dump implement IDebugPrints. And then a class which iterates over the list and called a method from IDebugPrints.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I was doing something stupid, which is why my test case didnt work and I posted in the first place. The answers below pointed that out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This compiles:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface IDebugPrints
{

}

public class Character : IDebugPrints
{

}

public class StoreList
{
    private List<IDebugPrints> internalList;

    public StoreList(List<IDebugPrints> inList)
    {
        internalList = inList;
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class Test1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var characters = new List<IDebugPrints>();
        characters.Add(new Character());
        var sl = new StoreList(characters);
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't initialize characters before passing it in. I have updated the code that compiles.

Comment: How will he instantiate `characters ` variable?

Comment: List<IDebugPrints> characters = new List<IDebugPrints>();

Comment: Out of interest, how would you recommend handling in the case where the Character class has multiple interfaces?  How would I declare the internal StoreList.List variable? (My case dosent, but I could see it happening). (oh, and Characters was initialized, I just didn't include that code. I will include everything in the future so not to mislead :) )

Comment: I would make it a list of objects and then cast it to the type you need layer. List<object>

Comment: Creating the list as IDebugPrints is rather poor. I'd rather not create a List of Characters as IDebugPrints, because you're missing the essential of creating that list. It's not about creating a list of `List<IDebugPrints>`, it's about creating a list of characters. The problem i have is, that linq won't work on your list. like `var result = characters.Where(character => character.LifePoints < 10);` won't work anymore. I'd rather go for my solution or the solution usr provided.

Answer (score 3):

Pass `List<Character> characters` as a `IEnumerable<IDebugPrint>`. This works beginning with C# 4.

Make `internalList` and `inList` typed as `IEnumerable<IDebugPrint>`.

Reference types are never copied in C# (except if explicitly implemented and requested by the programmer). .NET has no general way to copy an arbitrary reference type instance.

This means that your variables of type `IEnumerable<IDebugPrint>` will refer to the existing modifiable list.

Comment: Thank You. This is what I originally did, however there was a bug in a different section of code that lead me to believe there was a copy taking place. It was 4am :) I should have just went to bed and would have solved it quickly in the morning :)

Comment: I think this is a nice solution, i didn't knew that from c# 4 it was able to cast a `List<>` to an `IEnumerable<baseclass>`. The advantage of this solution is, that the StoreList isn't aware that the IEnumerable is a List. Also the `StoreList` doesn't need (isn't allowed) to add/remove items. Tnx for sharing.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't possible to cast a `List<x>` to a `List<y>`  directly, unless you're using casting methods like:
`List<x> listX = listY.Cast<x>();`

I would pass the `List<Character>` as an `IList` to the StoreList. 
With the `.OfType<>()` extension, you can iterate the childs of the type given.
This way, the list isn't copied.

This way your `StoreList` can iterate it, not depending on the types you passed, as long the items are inherited from `IDebugPrint`, the `ShowAllInfo` will show the `Info`.

Here's an example:

```
public interface IDebugPrints
{
    string Info { get; set; }

    void ShowInfo();
}

public class Character : IDebugPrints
{
    public string Info {get;set;}

    public void ShowInfo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Info);
    }
}

public class StoreList
{
    private IList internalList;

    public StoreList(IList inList)
    {
        internalList = inList;
    }

    public void ShowAllInfo()
    {
        // I love the OfType<>() extension, it only returns the items of type IDebugPrints.
        foreach (var item in internalList.OfType<IDebugPrints>())
            item.ShowInfo();
    }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Character> characters = new List<Character>();

        characters.Add(new Character { Info = "Character 1" });
        characters.Add(new Character { Info = "Character 2" });

        // And I want to pass that list
        StoreList sl = new StoreList(characters);


        sl.ShowAllInfo();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: See my posted solution.

Comment: This reminded me to look into using IList instead of the concete class. TY!